# Broken Pagination with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get my pagination to work but im having a problem, the "switching between" pagen wont work at all, and the results is not really working to well. Can someone help to get it working cause i cant for my life get it to work and i have tried so much :/

```
<?

 if (!(isset($pagenum))) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 

$currentpage = 20;
 $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs LIMIT $currentpage") or die(mysql_error()); 


//This is where you display your query results

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p )) 

 { 

  $id=$info['id'];
    echo '<a href="/index.php?dogs='. $id .'">
        <img src="/thumbs/'. $id .'.jpg" width="100" height="100"  alt="" />
    </a>';

 echo "<br>";

 } 

 echo "<p>";


 // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages

 echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";


 // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

 if ($pagenum == 1) 

 {

 } 

 else 

 {

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";

 echo " ";

 $previous = $pagenum-1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";

 } 


 //just a spacer

 echo " ---- ";


 //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links

 if ($pagenum == $last) 

 {

 } 

 else {

 $next = $pagenum+1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";

 echo " ";

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";

 } 

 ?>
```

Comment: What is `$pagenum` ? Is that a `$_GET` request?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are working with register_globals=on, you need to get initial pagenum value with `$_GET['pagenum']` instead of `$pagenum`

Comment: And also you should correct your query:
`LIMIT` only restrict number of results, for pagination you should specify the offset

Your offset should be `$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $pagenum` always after seting `$pagenum = $_GET["pagenum"];` as @mesutozer recommends you. The syntax for your query would be then `SELECT * FROM dogs LIMIT $offset, $currentpage`